# Automatic Reply from Distribution Group?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2010

I have a Distribution Group with three members in it. Currently I have a rule set up on my client-side Outlook to autoreply to any new emails sent to the DL, but it sends as my account so any replies to it only go to me.

What is the easiest way to set up an automatic reply? The group is mail enabled, I can change my "From" in Outlook to send as the group already. I just can't change the "From" field on the automatic reply.

Comment: What particular action do you use "reply using template" or "have server reply with a message"?